# How to match spaces and ascii characters in .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to match special characters in my `.htaccess` file for so an id value can return a page matching the correct id value.

In my MySQL field the text is: `Thelma & Louise`

Before the rewrite rule page address looked like this with all the property data populating the page `www.site.com/movie.php?id=Thelma+%26+Louise`

My `RewriteRule ^movie/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)/?$ /movie.php?id=$1`

The url comes out like this but with a page not found error

`www.site.com/movie/Thelma+%26+Louise`

How can I properly match the ascii characters so that the page is displayed.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI gets decoded before it gets run through any of the rewrite rules, so you need to match against a space  and an ampersand `&`. Your pattern, `([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)` needs to account for those symbols:

```
RewriteRule ^movie/([A-Za-z0-9_&+-\s]+)/?$ /movie.php?id=$1 [L,B]
```

Additionally, you need to use the `B` flag so that the grouped match `$1` gets propery encoded in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i wouldn't use any ascii characters in my url. Maybe try trimming them so you have thelma-louise or thelma+louise. But thats my personal experience.

Second, you rewrite to your ID with the name of the movie. Can't you do it like this:
movie/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+) movie.php?id=$2 so its looks something like movie/thelma-louise-101 Lots of movies have the same name. And now you know that IDS are at least an INT. Don't forget to check in PHP offcourse.

Answer (score 0):

Your second rule probably doesn't match. You could try to put all possible characters in your regex, but it is probably better to match all characters, but the characters you don't want to match. In this case that would probably be the `/` character:

```
RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]+)/?$ /movie.php?id=$1
```

Please note that you still have to make sure you are not creating an infinite loop.